# How do I limit image height to height of another flexbox column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout with two columns. Column one contains an image, at design time the aspect ratio of the image is unknown. I want to display the whole image while maintaining its aspect ratio. Column two contains several lines of text, length is unknown at design time. The container should not have a fixed height.

How can I maximize the space available in column one for the image, without the image height exceeding the height of (the text in) column two?

In the code snippet below I want the height of the black image to be less than or of the same height as the right column with gray background, it should never be taller.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}
.col1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.col2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/256x256/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Here's some text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the width of the text container fixed? or is it half of the container width?

Comment: It would not make sense if your text on the right side is really short, it would make more sense if the image is a set size with variable length amount of text on the right

Comment: Yes. I hope that is what is expected from @Tor Langlo

Answer (score 0):

You could have an average result via `height:0;` + `min-height:100%` , but parent's width will hardly be update .

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
   background-color: blue;
   justify-content:start;
}
.col1 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-self: stretch; 
}
.col2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
  flex:1 0 auto; 
}
img {  
  height:0;
  min-height: 100%; 
  min-width:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/256x256/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Here's some text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this kind of result you need to have one of the column's widths fixed.
In the below example I have fixed the width of the image to `256px`.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}
.col1 {
  flex: 0 0 256px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.col1 > img {
    width: 256px;
}
.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col1">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <p>Here's some text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
      <p>And some more text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```